# How to hide the address bar in iPhone browser, so that I can get a full screen view

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, cross-browser, phaser-framework

I am developing a web game using Phaser and i want the game to be in fullscreen mode. Since in iPhone it is not posible to go fullscreen mode, the bottom part of the game canvas is not visible because of the address bar. in android browser this is working fine because it allows to go fullscreen mode

I was trying to hide the address bar so that the game canvas will be fully visible, is there a way for me to hide the address bar in ios browser.
or Is there a way for me to get the address bar height so that I can substract that with the game canvas height to fit it in the view port

Comment: It's a common issue in iOS devices, see https://dev.to/maciejtrzcinski/100vh-problem-with-ios-safari-3ge9 for more info about it and workarounds.